# SQL Fulltext search unexpected ranking -

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

If I perform the following fulltext query:

```
 SELECT c.CategoryId As ID
      ,c.Title
      ,KEY_TBL.RANK AS [Rank]
  FROM dbo.Category AS c
  INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Category, Title, 'back lower pain') AS KEY_TBL ON c.CategoryId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
  WHERE c.IsActive = 1
  ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

And I have the following two entries in the Category Table

```
ID | Title      | Rank
-----------------------
12 | Lower Body | 34  
11 | Back Pain  | 34
```

I would have thought that given "Back Pain" matches two of the three words it would rank higher than "Lower Body" but this isn't the case, the ranks are equal, how can I structure the query so that the ranking reflects this?

Not sure if this is relevant but my Fulltext Index is declared as:

```
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
    ON [dbo].[Category]
        (Title)
    KEY INDEX [PK_Category_CategoryId]
    ON [FullTextCatalog]
    WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

Comment: Are there more rows in dbo.Category? Fulltext uses the OKAPI BM25 ranking formula for this search and with the inflections introduced by FREETEXTTABLE other entries will influence the final ranking.

Comment: Actually there are many other entries with the word "Pain" in them, that's what the issue is I believe.

Comment: Right, multiple entries will result in a lower weight being assigned to the term which is probably affecting the final rank of "back pain" even though it has two matching words in the search string.

Comment: So there's not anyway around this?

Comment: Are you committed to using FREETEXTTABLE for some reason? If not, then CONTAINSTABLE has the "ISABOUT WEIGHT(weight value)" modifier which lets you somewhat influence the rank value calculation for each matching row.